# Stop page load during navigate url in selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am using selenium tool in my C# windows application,

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
```

when the the application executing this line the page loads takes 2mins. 
During that time, the followin element has found within 10 sec.

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchTerm"))
```

I used `driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchTerm")).SendKeys(Keys.Escape);`
But it wont work properly. The problem is after complete the  page load then only the control execute next line . But I need to stop the page if the element has found.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try issuing the Escape press at the top level, not on the element itself:

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchTerm")) != null) {
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.SendKeys(Keys.Escape);
}
```

That seems to be the most common way of issuing a page load stop.

Comment: but how do I continually monitor the page?

Answer (score 0):

To stop page load at any moment you can use something like this:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = Brwsr.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("window.stop();");
```